# Is SJCL.random.startCollectors() automatic?

Tags: cryptography, entropy, sjcl

If I import sjcl.js, then put only

```
console.log(sjcl.random.isReady());
```

It returns 2. But I didn't run

```
sjcl.random.startCollectors();
```

So I'm wondering if the entropy collector is auto-started on loading.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the source code, it doesn't call startCollectors() when loaded. I think the reason it is ready right away is because it uses https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RandomSource/getRandomValues (if it is available) to add Entrophy. So my guess is you tested this in a browser that supports getRandomValues.